# Unable to compare the time field in dictionary to current time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am learning python. I am trying to compare the date  in `Time` field of a dictionary with the date in `current_time` and if it matches, i am trying to print the `key , id` in `JIRA_ISSUE` but however, python is throwing the invalid syntax error for TIME field. Any help would be appreciated.

input:

```
 jira_list = [{'Jira No': 'abc3', 'author': 'BaniHani,peter', 'Time': '2021-02-23T15:52:58.529-0500'}, {'Jira No': 'cde4', 'author': 'Bator, richard', 'Time': '2021-06-16T16:51:20.953-0400'}, {'Jira No': 'abc', 'author': 'Bator, alex', 'Time': '2021-06-16T16:51:20.953-0400'}, {'Jira No': 'GEN3', 'author': 'Bator, Lauren E.', 'Time': '2021-06-03T13:29:57.127-0400'}]
```

Code:

```
now = datetime.now()
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in jira_list:
    for key  in i:
        if (i[Time] == current_time):
            print (i[key] + ""+i[id])
```

Error:

```
    jira_list = [{'Jira No': <JIRA Issue: key='abc-94', id='9935377'>, 'author': 'Bator, peter', 'Time': '2021-08-25T18:22:43.502-0400'}, {'Jira No': <JIRA Issue: key='abc-93', id='9935370'>, 'author': 'Bator, Lauren E.', 'Time': '2021-08-25T18:22:12.648-0400'}, {'Jira No': <JIRA Issue: key='GEN3-85', id='9708381'>, 'author': 'Bator, peter', 'Time': '2021-11-18T14:25:17.774-0500'}]
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Well, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: The sequence {'Jira No': <JIRA Issue... is syntactically incorrect. Where does it come from?

Comment: Where does the "<JIRA Issue...>" come from? This is in fact not an allowed syntax.

Comment: Invalid syntax it is showing for the TIME not for the JIRA ISSU. Code formatting made it look like the syntax error is at the JIRA_ISSUE

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the datetime values into the same format so that they can be compared. I'm not sure if datetime values in milliseconds can ever match but anyway possible solution is the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

jira_list = [{'Jira No': 'abc3', 'author': 'BaniHani,peter', 'Time': '2021-02-23T15:52:58.529-0500'}, {'Jira No': 'cde4', 'author': 'Bator, richard', 'Time': '2021-06-16T16:51:20.953-0400'}, {'Jira No': 'abc', 'author': 'Bator, alex', 'Time': '2021-06-16T16:51:20.953-0400'}, {'Jira No': 'GEN3', 'author': 'Bator, Lauren E.', 'Time': '2021-06-03T13:29:57.127-0400'}]

current_time = datetime.now()

for i in jira_list:
    if parser.parse(i['Time']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") == current_time:
        print (i.keys(), i.values())
```

Prints something like that if the condition has met:

```
dict_keys(['Jira No', 'author', 'Time']) dict_values(['abc3', 'BaniHani,peter', '2021-02-23T15:52:58.529-0500'])
```